# Why does Linq BindingSource throw ObjectDisposedException?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, visual-studio-2015, bindingsource

I have a *BindingSource* that is populated with a *BindingList* when someone starts our Wizard form's process:

```
private void GetBillRuns(int billRunID)
{
    bindingSourceBillRun.DataSource =  ((IListSource)BillRunDC.ub_bill_runs.Where(b => b.bill_run_id == billRunID)).GetList() as BindingList<ub_bill_run>;
}
```

If someone clicks the Back button, they can select a different Wizard option and continue forward. The *EndEdit()* routine is called each time the Panel index is changed:

```
void EndEdit()
{
    bindingSourceBillRun.EndEdit();
}
```

In the Wizard form, when the Back button is clicked the *BindingSource* is Cleared. The *BindingSource* itself is never disposed of until the actual Wizard Form is closed and disposed.

We have an interesting bug:

- We can start our Wizard Panel Form, select an option and click Next.
- We can go Back 1 to the First Step in our Wizard Panel form.
- We can select a different option, click Next again, and we get an **ObjectDisposedException**.

As shown in the screenshot, the **ObjectDisposedException** has stopped the code. Also, you can see that I have hovered over the BindingSource, which is not disposed. Further, the DataSource associated with it has data which also does not appear to be disposed.

[image: screenshot]

Obviously, a different `billRunID` would be sent to the `GetBillRuns` query, depending on what screen option is selected at the start.

What is causing the **ObjectDisposedException**?

Does the *BindingSource* need to be cleared or something before refilling with the `GetBillRuns` method?

Comment: what about listening to `bindingSourceBillRun`'s Disposed event? I think the misunderstanding is that "after an object has been disposed the reference becomes a null pointer and thus hovering cursor over it should not show its members".

Comment: @kennyzx that was a good idea. I added a handler for the BindingSource's Disposed event, but it was never hit. I'm thinking there is something inside the BindingSource instance that is disposed. I don't know. I could just wrap it in a try/catch, but that just hacks a problem without understanding why it's going on.